# f(x)= number of ones in x . find the highest and average fitness for genetic algorithm , Alternate option to Map and reduce in python

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, fitness

i am trying to write a code which takes input as below and then find the highest and average where f(x)= number of ones in x .

```
['00111110011001010011', '01111101001101110010', '01100110111110000000', '01101101100111001001']
```

```
def fitness(genome):
    return reduce((lambda x, y: int(x) + int(y)), list(genome))

# reference : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reduce-in-python/

def evaluateFitness(population):
    sums = list(map(lambda x: fitness(x), population))
    return [max(sums), sum(sums) / len(population)]
```

the above function works well. i want to know if there is any library in numpy or scipy which can do the same or pygad.basically trying to find alternate option to achieve the same result.

Comment: Your `fitness` could also be `return genome.count('1')`.  And, if you're just calling a function that takes one parameter, you can do `list(map(fitness, population))`.  You don't need a lambda.

Comment: thats a good advice Tim, that simplifies the implementation to a great extent